# React does not work on my browser/ machine

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, compiler-errors, onclick

I am trying to creacte a pretty basic app with React using 3 elements: a profile card, an editable profile card and a button that switches the state of the app (useState) when clicked (from read to edit). I import all 3 from 'components' folder directly to the App file (classes only no nested components).

When clicking the button I get the following Error Message:
**Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the App component.**

I tested the code for several hours and it seems to be OK but still get the same Error.

**Profile Card In Read Mode**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Classes from "./profileCardRead.module.css";

class ProfileCardRead extends Component {
  state = {}
  
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("[ProfileCardRead] component did mount");
    //this.toggleEdit = this.toggleEdit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("[ProfileCardRead] component unmounted");
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={Classes.profileCard}>
          <div>
            <img className={Classes.profileImage} />
            <div className={Classes.nameDiv}>
              <h2>{props.fullname}</h2>
            </div>
            <h3>{props.role}</h3>
          </div>
          <div className={Classes.leftDiv}>
            <h4>{props.status}</h4>
            <h4>{props.personalID}</h4>
            <h4>{props.city}</h4>
            <h4>{props.dischargeDate}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default new ProfileCardRead();
```

**Profile Card In Edit Mode**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Classes from "./profileCardEdit.module.css";

class ProfileCardEdit extends Component {
  state= {}

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("[ProfileCardEdit] component did mount");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("[ProfileCardEdit] component unmounted");
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <div className={Classes.profileCard}>
        <div>
          <input id="" class="" type="image" placeholder="הוסף תמונה"></input>
          <input type="text" placeholder="שם מלא"></input>
          <input type="text" placeholder="תפקיד"></input>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" placeholder="סטטוס"></input>
          <input type="text" placeholder="מ.א"></input>
          <input type="text" placeholder="עיר"></input>
          <input type="date" placeholder="תץ שחרור"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default new ProfileCardEdit();
```

**App.js**

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import ProfileCardEdit from "./components/profileCard/profileCardEdit/profileCardEdit.js";
import ProfileCardRead from "./components/profileCard/profileCardRead/profileCardRead.js";
import EditBtn from "./components/controlBtns/editBtn.js";
//import e from "cors";

class App extends Component {
  state = { readMode: true };

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log("component did mount");
    //return true;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("component unmounted");
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  }

  clickHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ readMode: false});
    console.log(this.state.readMode);
  };

  render = () => {
    let JSX = null;

    if (this.state.readMode === true) {
      JSX = (
        <ProfileCardRead.render
          fullname="שם מלא"
          role="תפקיד"
          status="סטטוס"
          personalID="מ.א"
          city="עיר"
          dischargeDate="ת. שחרור"
        />
      );
    }
    
    else if (this.state.readMode === false) {
      JSX = <ProfileCardEdit.render/>
    }
      
    else {
      JSX = null
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hi I am a react app</h1>
        {JSX}
        <EditBtn.render clickHandler={() => this.clickHandler()}>
          edit
        </EditBtn.render>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default new App();
```

I copied some dummy code from react documentation (same princple a button with some reaction fllowed by user click) in order to check if this problem is on my machine or the browser rather my code and got some other Errors that I could not solve (although as said the code was copied from the original React site).

please help me solve this issue, thanks ahead.

Comment: The code you pasted doesn't even use setState. Could you try to create a minimal example?

Comment: Include the relevant code. By your own admission, the following code "got some other Errors that I could not solve" but you don't say what those errors are. Where is the code with `setState`? Include a [mre]